# Finding geo spatial with morphia mongodb using Java

Tags: java, mongodb, geospatial, morphia

I would like to query some geo location points with morphia framework. I use my latitude, longitude, and radius(100 km.) with "Near" method to query the other around my location and limit 10 results. Just like this :

```
morphia.ds.find(Location.class).field("Location").near(latitude, longitude, 100).limit(10).asList();
```

It doesn't error but the result shows me the location points that around me and out of scope of my radius(100km.). So, my radius doesn't concern when query the result.

What is my problem with query statement?

Thanks you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The length of an arcdegree of north-south latitude difference, is about 60 nautical miles, 111 kilometres or 69 statute miles at any latitude; You can read more about here in [wikipedia](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Longitude#Degree_length) or in mongo geospatial page The [Earth is Round but Maps are Flat](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing).

Convert distance by 111.12 (one degree is approximately 111.12 kilometers) when using km, or by 69 (for miles).

So change your query to

```
morphia.ds.find(Location.class).field("Location").near(latitude, longitude, 100/111.12).limit(10).asList();
```

And make sure mongodb accepts the co-ordinates in [long,lat].

Comment: Thank you for good answer. I have already read your's links and more understand the radius distance with method of mongo db.

Comment: How to add an index for it?

Answer (score 3):

According to the website ([MongoDB: Calculate Distances in a 2d Index Using Spherical Geometry](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/calculate-distances-using-spherical-geometry-with-2d-geospatial-indexes/)) to get the radians of the distance where we look, we have to use the land within 3.959 miles or 6.371 km.

Viewing the documentation ([MongoDB:$nearSphere](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/nearSphere/#op._S_nearSphere)) I think the call should be:

```
morphia.ds.find(Location.class).field("Location").near(latitude, longitude, 100/6371, true).limit(10).asList();
```

In my case and after some checking, this is how I work.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void test() {
        DB datastore = ConnectionFactory.getInstance().getDatabaseMongo();
        double[] near = { 20.593684, 78.96288 };
        BasicDBObject basicDBObject = new BasicDBObject();
        basicDBObject.put("type", "Point");
        basicDBObject.put("coordinates", near);
        BasicDBObject geoNearParams = new BasicDBObject();
        geoNearParams.append("geoNear", <Collection name>);
        geoNearParams.append("near", basicDBObject);
        geoNearParams.append("spherical", true);
        geoNearParams.append("maxDistance", 100);
        geoNearParams.append("limit", 10);
        CommandResult commandResult = datastore.command(geoNearParams);
        commandResult.getErrorMessage();
        Object data = commandResult.get("results");
        System.out.println(data.toString());
    }
```